# converting formula result to string using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i am working on a project which requires me to spit out data from access onto an excel and then finally export into SQL after doing some calculations in excel. When i get the data from Access into excel i am using excel formulas like

```
=RIGHT(F87616,4)
```

and

```
=IFERROR(MID(F87616,1,FIND("-",F87616,1)-1),"")
```

Now, what i want to do is, replace this formula with result of these cells so that when i export from Excel to SQL, i can pick up this data as a string.

I know it may sound very confusing but basically i am trying to replace the formulas with the result that i would get after calculating values using the formulas. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Record a macro to select the cells and do a pastespecial values. See what code do you get :)

Comment: This isn't confusing -- it's a common requirement. Do what Siddharth said and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing something to one cell in particular, you can do *range*.Value (as opposed to *range*.Formula or *range*.FormulaR1C1 both of which return the formula and not the result).